# display nothing on removing file

Tags: javascript

```js
function previewImage() {
  var thisElement = event.target
  var file = thisElement.files;
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    thisElement.nextElementSibling.querySelector("img").setAttribute("src", event.target.result);
  }
  if (file.length) {
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0])
  } else {
    fileReader.readAsDataURL()
  }
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-warning">
    <h4 class="d-inline">PHOTO*</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark">
    <input type="file" id="file1" accept="image/*" class="form-control" onchange="previewImage();" required>
    <label for="file1" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 170px;">
<img id="display1" class="w-100 h-100" style="cursor: pointer;">
</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

I making a form where I need to upload image & display it & it displayed.
But the problem is when I remove the image then also it display the image.

Comment: Where in this code are you removing the image?

Comment: What is your Expectation? Do you want to remove the Image? Please Clear that

Comment: @Shrey yes when i remove the file it will not dislay anything

Comment: There is no button where you are trying to remove the file.  It is giving error when you try to change the file. And you want to fix that error. Am I right?

Comment: When `file.length` is 0, it means the file has been removed. You shouldn't display anything in that case.

Comment: remove else condition code so then there is no error if you cancel file upload.

Comment: first upload the file then click again on choose file to upload then click on cancel you can see there is file displayed but there is no file chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of `fileReader.readAsDataURL();` in `if-else` statement. Just `if` statement is necessary for Previewing image.

The `readAsDataURL()` method is used to read the contents of the specified Blob or File. Parameter is neccessary in that method. Which is missing in your `else` statement.

```js
function previewImage() {
  let thisElement = event.target;
  let file = thisElement.files;
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  let img = document.querySelector("img"); 
  fileReader.onload = function(event) {
    img.setAttribute("src", event.target.result);
  };
  if (file.length) {
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
  } else {
    img.src='';
  }
};
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center bg-warning">
    <h4 class="d-inline">PHOTO*</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="border border-dark">
    <input type="file" id="file1" onchange="previewImage()" accept="image/*" class="form-control" required>
    <label for="file1" class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height: 170px;">
<img id="display1" class="w-100 h-100" style="cursor: pointer;">
</label><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: first upload the file then click again on choose file to upload then click on cancel you can see there is file displayed but there is no file chosen.

Comment: Snippet updated ! Please see if that works